# Centering line label on node

Tags: qgis, labeling

I'm labelling the starting point of a line to give an indication of direction for referenced photos. I've found the first node of the line somewhat long-windedly as per screenshot, but I'm not sure how to centre the label on it.

An alignment expression seem like it would be the ticket but I think I'm struggling with how to define the label rather than the line geometry in order to relate them.

Browsing past questions it seem like I could've just gone with `xat (0)` for the first node, duly noted!

Edit - I was treating the strings in the Alignment expression like a function, without quotes.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm not sure how to reply to moderator edits but centre/centring is British English, not a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to place the label at the start of the line, try to use the following formula for x coordinate:

```
x_at(0)
```

And use the following formula for y coordinate:

```
y_at(0)
```

To align the labels at the center of the circle in your example, you need to use the `Alignment horizontal and vertical`:

[image]

In alignment `horizontal` write `'Center'`, and alignment `vertical` write `'Half'`. You will get the following result, which is exactly what you need:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant thanks! I thought I'd already tried this, but I was treating them as a function, without the quotes.